# SignalR argument serialization issue

Tags: c#, json.net, signalr

I have a strange issue with SignalR, where I have a simple hub which accepts a model like so:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public Guid PersistedId
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I look in the request object, the post going over to the server is:

```
{"H":"entryhub","M":"SendEntry","A":["{\"Version\":\"1.0.0\",\"PersistedId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"ParentId\":\"1764a2e3-ff6f-4a17-9c5f-d99642301dbf\",\"Content\":\"test\",\"DateCreated\":\"2013-07-21T14:06:01.980Z\",\"CreatorAccountId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}"],"I":2}
```

I keep getting the response with the exception:

```
{"I":"2","E":"Error converting value \"{\"Version\":\"1.0.0\",\"PersistedId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"ParentId\":\"1764a2e3-ff6f-4a17-9c5f-d99642301dbf\",\"Content\":\"test\",\"DateCreated\":\"2013-07-21T14:06:01.980Z\",\"CreatorAccountId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}\" to type 'SharedPlugin.Models.Entry'. Path '', line 1, position 266.","T":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JRawValue.ConvertTo(Type type)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultParameterResolver.ResolveParameter(ParameterDescriptor descriptor, IJsonValue value)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ZipIterator>d__7a`3.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultParameterResolver.ResolveMethodParameters(MethodDescriptor method, IList`1 values)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.InvokeHubPipeline(IHub hub, IJsonValue[] parameterValues, MethodDescriptor methodDescriptor, HubRequest hubRequest, StateChangeTracker tracker)"}
```

Now I thought maybe it was Json.net having issues with the underlying serialization, however I wrote a unit test taking the exact same json string from the post request, and deserializing it to an Entry object, and it works fine.

I have checked online but there doesn't seem to be much info on the error. I would assume it could be the date, but have tried setting my own JsonNetSerializer` and changing the way it handles dates, nulls, missing members etc, however nothing seems to help, and in the unit test it has no settings other than default and works fine, so this implies it is not an issue with Json.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was down to double serialization, as I was calling ko.toJSON on my object rather than ko.toJS.

> ko.toJSON — this produces a JSON string representing your view model’s
> data. Internally, it simply calls ko.toJS on your view model, and then uses the browser’s native > JSON serializer on the result. Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON > serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the json2.js library.
>
> ko.toJS — this clones your view model’s object graph, substituting for each observable the > current value of that observable, so you get a plain copy that contains only your data and no > Knockout-related artifacts

It was only after talking to dfowler I realised that this was the case and the request data shows the json as a single string, not a complete json object as expected. So dont double serialize!

Comment: Could you expand on your solution? I'm having the same issue as well.